# Access product.id in index.liquid page in Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, e-commerce, shopify

I want to access `product.id` in `index.liquid` page in Shopify, so that I can provide some feedback on the newly sold product.
Any way to achieve that.
Tried this

```
{% for product in collections.frontpage.products %}
```

But it doesn't fetch all products in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out :)

```
{% for product in collections.all.products%}
<div id="shopify-product-reviews" data-id="{{product.id}}">
```

This was all I needed to do.